# Longest path in BTS ,how to do the diameter

Tags: assembly, mips

I already opened a question about this, but I did progress.
so I'm trying to implement in MIPS the diameter of the tree.

Thanks to Peter Cordes that helped me figure out some things  [on my previous question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315470/longest-path-in-binary-tree-in-mips).
So I did already the implementation of the height of the tree :

```
.data
tree: .word a
a: .word 5, bb, c
bb: .word 2, d, e 
c: .word 1, 0, 0
d: .word 5, f, g
e: .word 9, 0, h
f: .word 0, 0, 0
g: .word 6, i, 0
h: .word 55, 0, jj
i: .word 4, 0, 0
jj: .word 8, 0, 0 
.text
main: 
la $a0, tree
lw $a0,0($a0)
jal heightOfTree
move $a0, $v0 
li $v0, 1 # Print the return value
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
heightOfTree:
bnez $a0, Recursion
li $v0, 0 # Base case
jr $ra
Recursion: #Recursive call height of tree = max (height(leftchild),(height(rightchild)) + 1
addiu $sp, $sp, -12 
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)
lw $a0, 4($a0) # height(rightchild)
jal heightOfTree
sw $v0, 8($sp) # Saving the height of the left child
lw $a0, 4($sp) # Taking the Address of the root
lw $a0, 8($a0) # height of right child
jal heightOfTree
lw $t0, 8($sp) # In $t0 the height of the left child ,In $v0 of the right child.
bge $v0, $t0, maximum # Calcolating the max between the left and right (left height - $t0)(right -height - $v0)
move $v0, $t0
maximum: 
addiu $v0, $v0, 1
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addiu $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra #Returning the height to the main
```

It works perfect but I'm not succeeding in calculating the diameter :(

I'm working by this code

```
int diameter (node *P)
{
if (p==NULL)
    return 0;
int lheight = height(P->left);
int rheight = height(P->right);
int ldiameter = diameter(p->left);
int rdiameter = diameter(p->right);
int longestpath = max (lheight+rheight+1,max(ldiameter,rdiameter)

return longestpath
```

the diameter should be 7

Comment: *I'm not succeeding in calculating the diameter* isn't specific enough for a [mcve].  What *does* happen when you run your code?  And what do you see with a debugger.

Comment: Should be 2 recursive functions, but I don't know how to connect them in one, should I allocate another stack in the second recursion? :/
Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Also, why don't you just use a global register to find the max path length, instead of returning it up the recursion?  It means you have to write `height()` separately from `diameter()`, so you need a lot more code, and your code has to traverse the tree twice.  (Actually the amount of extra work is higher than that; For each node you visit in a `diameter` traversal, you also traverse all its children in a `height` traversal, so it's more like O(n^2) where mine was O(n).  Much more crap to single-step through while debugging.)

Comment: *but I don't know how to connect them in one*  Huh? You're already calling `height` from `diameter`, so they're "connected".   To make a recursive call, you store local state on the stack and then `jal diameter`, just like you were doing for `jal height`.

Comment: You are right Peter, I search for some info about this global register,Thank you.

Comment: My answer on your previous question was pretty specific about suggesting `$t8` and `$t9` for those variables.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but for me it's a bit hard to understand :( I'm not native speaker, also i'm very stressed I have to send it today hhhh
Thanks for trying help me,very appreciate it :)